# Google geochart display couple regions

Tags: jquery, google-maps, maps, google-visualization, interactive

My problem is that I'm trying to create interactive map (region Eurasia) but google geochart tool is limited and there is no region Eurasia...

I tryed to connect couple regions europe and asia but also I got problems with that..

So is it possible to display couple regions ? If not maybe do you know any tool (except google geochart) to generate interactive maps ?

Answer (score 0):

Custom map regions like Eurasia is not supported in Google GeoChart, which is one main reason we have  [VectorWorkz GeoChart](http://vectorworkz.com/). We can quickly provide a Eurasia region with just the countries you need. Check it out.

[Here](http://vectorworkz.com/products/geochart/compare-with-google-geochart) is a comparison of the Google and VectorWorkzGeoChart.